# In R how do I extract rows based on another data frame where the values don't need to be exact? They just need to be close enough?

Tags: r, merge

I have two data frames with mostly the same values

df1:

```
v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 v7 ......

500 40 5.2 z1 .....

500 40 7.2 z2 .....

500 40 9.0 z3 .....

500 40 3.5 z4 .....

500 40 4.2 z5 .....
```

df2:

```
v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 v7 .....

500 40 5.1 m1 .....

500 40 7.9 m2 .....

500 20 8.6 m3 .....

500 40 3.7 m4 .....

500 40 4.0 m5 .....
```

I would like to merge (or any function like it) so that my new df1 file has exact matching v1 and v2, but v3 does not need to be strictly exact. Is there a way I can match v3 to within +/- 0.2?

I would like the final df1 to look like:

```
v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 v7 .....

500 40 5.2 z1 .....

500 40 3.5 z4 .....

500 40 4.2 z5 .....
```

I get as far as below, but I'm not sure how to account for the variability of column v3.

```
hed <- c("v1", "v2", "v3") #original data didn't have header
df1_final <- merge(df1, df2[hed],by=hed)
```

If there is a better language to deal with this I'd accept that too, but this is only one part to an entire R script i'm working on.

Answer (score 5):

Using the `tidyverse` we could first `join`, then `filter` with `near` (and a tolerance):

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- data_frame(v1 = c(500, 500, 500, 500, 500),
                  v2 = c(40, 40, 40, 40, 40),
                  v3 = c(5.2, 7.2, 9.0, 3.5, 4.2),
                  v4 = c("z1", "z2", "z3", "z4", "z5"))

df2 <- data_frame(v1 = c(500, 500, 500, 500, 500),
                  v2 = c(40, 40, 20, 40, 40),
                  v3 = c(5.1, 7.9, 8.6, 3.7, 4.0),
                  v4 = c("m1", "m2", "m3", "m4", "m5"))

df1 %>%
  full_join(df2, by = c("v1", "v2")) %>%    # join on v1 and v2
  filter(near(v3.x, v3.y, tol = 0.21)) %>%  # filter with a tolerance
  rename(v3 = v3.x, v4 = v4.x) %>%          # rename the columns
  select(v1:v4)                             # select em
```

This yields

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
     v1    v2    v3 v4   
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1  500.   40.  5.20 z1   
2  500.   40.  3.50 z4   
3  500.   40.  4.20 z5
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're familiar with SQL syntax this (and a lot of other complicated non-equal merges) is easy with `sqldf`

```
library(sqldf)
df1 <- data.frame(v1 = c(500, 500, 500, 500, 500),
                  v2 = c(40, 40, 40, 40, 40),
                  v3 = c(5.2, 7.2, 9.0, 3.5, 4.2),
                  v4 = c("z1", "z2", "z3", "z4", "z5"))

df2 <- data.frame(v1 = c(500, 500, 500, 500, 500),
                  v2 = c(40, 40, 20, 40, 40),
                  v3 = c(5.1, 7.9, 8.6, 3.7, 4.0),
                  v4 = c("m1", "m2", "m3", "m4", "m5"))


sqldf('
  select df1.* 
  from df1
  join df2 
    on df1.v3 <= df2.v3+0.2
    and df1.v3 >= df2.v3-0.2
')
```